# Not able to integrate neo4j with my existing maven project

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I am trying to integrate neo4j with my existing maven project. Neo4j application as a standalone working properly but after integration, I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.labelscan.LuceneLabelScanIndex.(LuceneLabelScanIndex.java:55)
```

I have added neo4j lib in the classpath.

Comment: What dependencies have you added?

Comment: I have added all the jar  present in neo4j/lib as external jar in my project

Comment: If you use maven, I would suggest adding neo4j dependencies there to be sure it pulls in all its related dependencies